# sqlite - subquery for table name

Tags: sqlite, subquery, tablename

I use SQLite.
How can I use something like this:

```
INSERT INTO (
    SELECT `table_name`
    FROM `tables`
    WHERE `id`=1)(`data_column_name`)
VALUES ('some data')
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) you cannot. The `INSERT` statement takes a table name - with an optional schema name - not an expression.

You would have to evaluate the `SELECT` and then build the `INSERT` statement.